# Right way to use generics for HashMap

Tags: generics, for-loop, hashmap

I am working on storing employee data in HashMap. I have used following code for storing Employee details. I am storing employee id as a key and employee bean as a value.

```
Map<String, Object> empData = new HashMap<String, Object>();
```

My senior told me the generics used is not proper. I am skeptical why he said like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply add your types to collection,

```
 empData<EmpIdType,EmpBean> = new HashMap<>()
```

Since we don't want to do explicit casting and generics makes it clear.
when you access the value and assign it to other object you need to cast to its type.

That defeats the generics purpose.

Also when you didn't mention the type in generics, you may end up putting different values that's not the collection is created for.

you may put some wrong type within your empData.
say you've other candidatesId and candidatesDetail, if you don't mention the type when creating the empData you can put

```
empData.put(sampleCandidatesId,sampleCandidatesDetails)
```

which is obviously wrong.

Comment: What is the harm in using <String, Object>?

Comment: @user2074417 You lose the type safety of `<String, Bean>,` and you force a lot of typecasts to be necessary in the code.